# Difference between QGIS export and gdalwarp

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gdalwarp

Does QGIS export/save as use a different projection system/process than gdalwarp? I am working with MASIE ice coverage data available [here](ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/DATASETS/NOAA/G02186//geotiff/4km/ice_only/2021). My goal is to automate the process of reprojecting the daily images to EPSG 4326; source images are in EPSG 7239. Performing reprojection tests with gdalwarp provided unsatisfactory results, however when the file is manually saved from within QGIS (and providing a CRS of 4326 - see image below) the results are as expected).

My questions are:

1. Does QGIS Export / Save as CRS projection perform a different reprojection than gdalwarp
2. To use gdalwarp to achieve the desired output is there an intermediate step(s) required to reproject a raster from EPSG 7239 to EPSG 4326

**QGIS Export / Save as with reprojection**
[image: QGIS Export / Save as with reprojection]

**QGIS Export / Save as with reprojection results - desired output**
[image: QGIS manual export reprojection]

**gdalwarp code used to reproject**

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -r near -of GTiff "/Users/ryangarnett/OneDrive - Global Spatial Technology Solutions Inc/Documents/Data/masie_ice/source/masie_ice_r00_v01_2021005_4km.tif" "/Users/ryangarnett/OneDrive - Global Spatial Technology Solutions Inc/Documents/Data/masie_ice/temp/masie_ice_r00_v01_2021005_4km_4326.tif"
```

**gdalwarp reprojection results - unsuccessful output**
[image: gdalwarp reprojection]

**UPDATE**

Output from gdalinfo based on comment request

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: /Users/ryangarnett/OneDrive - Global Spatial Technology Solutions Inc/Documents/Data/masie_ice/source/masie_ice_r00_v01_2021005_4km.tif
Size is 6144, 6144
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["Stereographic_North_Pole",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Polar_Stereographic"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",60],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-80],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (-12288000.000000000000000,12288000.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (4000.000000000000000,-4000.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2021:01:06 07:36:19
  TIFFTAG_DOCUMENTNAME=/share/apps/G02186/production/output/geotiff/4km/ice_only/2021/masie_ice_r00_v01_2021005_4km.tif
  TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION=IDL TIFF file
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=IDL 8.3, Exelis Visual Information Solutions, Inc.
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=100
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=100
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-12288000.000,12288000.000) (145d 0' 0.00"E, 21d29'36.71"S)
Lower Left  (-12288000.000,-12288000.000) (125d 0' 0.00"W, 21d29'36.71"S)
Upper Right (12288000.000,12288000.000) ( 55d 0' 0.00"E, 21d29'36.71"S)
Lower Right (12288000.000,-12288000.000) ( 35d 0' 0.00"W, 21d29'36.71"S)
Center      (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) ( 80d 0' 0.00"W, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
```

Comment: What do you get with `gdalinfo "/Users/ryangarnett/OneDrive - Global Spatial Technology Solutions Inc/Documents/Data/masie_ice/source/masie_ice_r00_v01_2021005_4km.tif"`?

Comment: Thanks for the help, output is too long for the comments, so I will update the question to add the the gdalinfo output

Comment: I could reproduce the issue. Can you meanwhile confirm that with another file `gdalwarp -t epsg:4326  masie_ice_r07_v01_2021001_4km.tif warp_test.tif` the result is OK?

Comment: Sure let me do that

Comment: EPSG registry https://epsg.org/search/by-name does not know EPSG:7239. How do you know that it is the code to use?

Comment: I can confirm that the regional data (masie_ice_r07_v01_2021001_4km.tif) looks correct when I perform a gdalwarp on it.

Comment: Good question. I saw that too on the registry. What I did was download the shapefile extent that is available. When you look at the prj file and put it into the registry it comes up with 7239. Comparing the outputs from the two sources are identical. So with that, I made the assumption that the EPSG code is 7239.

Comment: I would say that it is better not to use too much time with this. Write mail to gdal-dev mailing list and include a link to this question. You need a real specialist to have a look at this case. QGIS does the job right for me too. Palette may play some role (QGIS drops the palette and writes plain grayscale) but a test with an image I created with pct2rgb.py did not give good warped result either.

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

After some more testing and trials a colleague figured a process to make a successful transformation. Reprojecting the raster from 7239 to 9040, and then reproject from 9040 to 4326. This two step approach seems to work exactly as expected.